# JES - Gray Posterize

Tags: python, loops, arraylist, jython, jes

So here is a simple function to gray posterize an image. With gray point = 64

```
def grayPosterize(pic):
 grayPoint = 64
 for p in getPixels(pic):
  r = getRed(p)
  g = getGreen(p)
  b = getBlue(p)
  luminiance = (r+g+b)/3
  if luminance < grayPoint:
   setColor(p,black)
  if luninance >= grayPoint:
   setColor(p,white)
```

Because this program uses 64 as the gray point, sometimes bright picture turns into all white and dark picture turn into all black.

I want the program instead of using 64 as a gray point, try all of the possible gray points (0 to 256) to find the best possible posterize picture result (by using distance to find the closest picture to the original)

An example of code to compare the different.

```
def imageDiff(img1,img2):
  if getWidth(img1)!=getWidth(img2) or getHeight(img1)!=getHeight(img2):
    print "Error calculating the image difference. img1 dimensions different to img2 dimensions!"
    return -1

  totalDistance=0
  for px1 in getPixels(img1):
    x=getX(px1)
    y=getY(px1)
    px2=getPixel(img2,x,y)
    clr1=getColor(px1)
    clr2=getColor(px2)
    totalDistance=totalDistance+ distance(clr1,clr2)
  return totalDistance
```

How would I do that?

Thanks in advance.